# Profile Views OSSN

Tags: php, oop, pdo

Hello everyone I am currently trying to build onto a component of OSSN, Profile Views, as it stands the component shows you what users viewed your profile. I am trying to get the number of viewers how have viewed your account to be displayed by a link to the Profile Viewers. I am not a fluent coder by no means but I have picked apart the code and found what could be useful in displaying the result.

In a component, two files are required to work. One is to register the language.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Open Source Social Network
 *
 * @package   (softlab24.com).ossn
 * @author    OSSN Core Team <info@softlab24.com>
 * @copyright 2014-2017 SOFTLAB24 LIMITED
 * @license   General Public Licence http://www.opensource-socialnetwork.org/licence
 * @link      https://www.opensource-socialnetwork.org/
 */

$en = array(
    'profileviews' => 'Profile Views:' . '<b>&nbsp'. $count . '</b>',
);

ossn_register_languages('en', $en);
```

The other is the functions passed to the system.

```
<?php
/**
 * Open Source Social Network
 *
 * @packageOpen Source Social Network
 * @author    Open Social Website Core Team <info@informatikon.com>
 * @copyright 2014 iNFORMATIKON TECHNOLOGIES
 * @license   General Public Licence http://www.opensource-socialnetwork.org/licence
 * @link      http://www.opensource-socialnetwork.org/licence
 */

define("__who_view_profile_type__", 'profile:viewed');


function who_viewed_my_profile_init() {
        if(ossn_isLoggedin()) {
                ossn_register_callback('page', 'load:profile', 'who_viewed_my_profile', 'ossn_relationships');
                ossn_register_page('profileviews', 'profileviews');
                ossn_register_sections_menu('newsfeed', array(
                        'name' => 'profileviews' . '<b>&nbsp'. $count . '</b>',
                        'text' => ossn_print('profileviews'), 
                        'url' => ossn_site_url('profileviews'),
                        'parent' => 'links',
                        'icon' => true

                ));

        }

}


function profileviews() {
        $looks = ossn_get_relationships(array(
                'to' => ossn_loggedin_user()->guid,
                'type' => __who_view_profile_type__
        ));

        $count = ossn_get_relationships(array(
                'to' => ossn_loggedin_user()->guid,
                'type' => __who_view_profile_type__,
                'count' => true

        ));

        if($looks) {
                foreach($looks as $item) {
                        $user = ossn_user_by_guid($item->relation_from);
                        if($user) {
                                $users[] = $user;
                        }
                }
        }

        $vars['users']     = $users;
        $vars['icon_size'] = 'small';

        $lists = "<div class='ossn-page-contents'>" .  $count;
        $lists .= "<p><strong>" . ossn_print('profileviews') . "</strong></p> ";
        $lists .= ossn_plugin_view("output/users_list", $vars);
        $lists .= ossn_view_pagination($count);
        $lists .= "</div>";

        $contents = array(
                'content' => $lists
        );
        $content  = ossn_set_page_layout('newsfeed', $contents, $count);
        echo ossn_view_page($title, $content);

}
function who_viewed_my_profile() {
        $profile = ossn_user_by_guid(ossn_get_page_owner_guid());
        $user    = ossn_loggedin_user();
        if(!$profile || !$user) {
                return false;
        }
        if(!ossn_relation_exists($profile->guid, $user->guid, __who_view_profile_type__)) {
                ossn_add_relation($profile->guid, $user->guid, __who_view_profile_type__);
        }
}



ossn_register_callback('ossn', 'init', 'who_viewed_my_profile_init');
```

From what I can tell the function `function profileviews()`
contains what I need to display the number of views. This array accounts how many users viewed the profile.

```
$count = ossn_get_relationships(array(
                'to' => ossn_loggedin_user()->guid,
                'type' => __who_view_profile_type__,
                'count' => true

        ));
```

My problem is when I try to call the function I am left with a blank homepage. Yet it works on the actual users page. The blank page shows no error.

"A system error has occurred. Please try again later. You may email the details of this error to the system administrator at"

Maybe I am calling the function wrong?

```
ossn_register_callback('ossn', 'init', 'who_viewed_my_profile_init', 'profileviews');
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute can be passed to the ossn_print function

```
function who_viewed_my_profile_init() {
        if(ossn_isLoggedin()) {
            $count = ossn_get_relationships(array(
                'to' => ossn_loggedin_user()->guid,
                'type' => __who_view_profile_type__,
                'count' => true

               ));
               ........
               ........
                ossn_register_sections_menu('newsfeed', array(
                        'name' => 'profileviews',
                        'text' => ossn_print('profileviews', array($count)), 
                        ......

                ));

        }

}
```

Then in langauge file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Open Source Social Network
 *
 * @package   (softlab24.com).ossn
 * @author    OSSN Core Team <info@softlab24.com>
 * @copyright 2014-2017 SOFTLAB24 LIMITED
 * @license   General Public Licence http://www.opensource-socialnetwork.org/licence
 * @link      https://www.opensource-socialnetwork.org/
 */

$en = array(
    'profileviews' => 'Profile Views: <b>%s</b>',
);

ossn_register_languages('en', $en);
```